# Pass a node reference to a module form

Tags: nodes, database

I've created a bid module that allows the users to bid on an auction through a node reference. I'm using `hook_form_alter()` to create the form on the 'create bid' page, and I would like to perform some SQL queries dealing with the referenced node.

How do I load the node reference?

Answer (score 1):

To load a node, use

```
node_load($nid);
```

This requires that the node is saved and that you have it's nid.

*To give a better answer more details are needed*

Comment: I'm developing a Drupal module for a client website. The custom content type is called bid. I've created one field using cck that is a node reference. The other fields are generated inside the module using hook_form_alter, hook_form_state etc. On the create bid page the cck field loads the nodereference through the url. Example: http://example.com/node/add/bid/75/. How do I access the referenced node inside my .module file where the form is generated? In other words, how do I load the info (nid, user, path, etc.) for the referenced node within my custom .module script? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If it's part of the path, you can get it from either the menu() hook, or just grabbing it out of $_GET['q'] or arg(#).  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6 for more info. In this case it would be arg(3) though.